# If $\lim_{n\to \infty }f_n(x)=f(x)$ a.e. does $f$ measurable ? Moreover, how to prove it?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal F,\mu)$ a measurable space and $f_n:X\to \mathbb R$ a sequence of measurable function that converges a.e. to $f$. In my exam this morning the ask if $f$ is measurable or not, and to give a proof or a counter example. I said yes, but I wasn't able to prove that $f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal F$ for all Borel set $B$. Since $B$ is generated by set of the form $(-\infty ,x]$ where $x\in \mathbb R$, it's enough to prove that $f^{-1}(-\infty ,x]\in \mathcal F$ for all $x$. I know that $f_n(-\infty ,x]\in \mathcal F$ for all $x$, so, don't we have that $f(-\infty ,x]=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}f^{-1}_n(-\infty ,x]$ forall $x$ ? For me it would make sense, but a friend that he think that is not true, but I don't understand why it's not true. Any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

- If $\mathcal F$ is complete, then it's true since $$f(x)=\limsup_{n\to \infty }f_n(x),\quad \mu-\text{a.e.}$$
  Since $g_n(x):=\sup_{k\geq n}f_k(x)$ is decreasing, you get that $$\{f(x)\geq \alpha  \}=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\{g_n(x)\geq \alpha \},$$
  which is measurable because $g_n$ is measurable. Indeed, $$\{g_n(x)>\alpha \}=\bigcup_{k\geq n}\{f_k(x)>\alpha \}\in \mathcal F.$$
- If $\mathcal F$ is not complete, the answer is no in general since all measurable function has a non measurable copy, i.e. if $f$ is measurable, there is $g$ non measurable s.t. $f=g$ $\mu-$a.e. Nevertheless, if $$\lim_{n\to \infty }f_n(x)=f(x),$$
  for all $x$, then the answer is yes.

---

Remark that $$f^{-1}(-\infty ,x]=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}f_n^{-1}(-\infty ,x]\tag{*}$$ can't be true in general. Indeed, if it would be true, it would implies that all convergent sequence of continuous function converges to continuous function, which is not true.

Comment: Where is the completeness of $\mathcal{F}$ used in the first part?

Comment: @RobertW.: $\{f(x)\geq \alpha \}=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\{g_n\geq \alpha \}$ is not true if $\mathcal F$ is not complete (this equality is true up to a set of measure $0$ only)

Comment: So you mean that $\{f\ge \alpha\}\cap E=\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\{g_n\ge \alpha\}\cap E$, where $E^c$ is a null set?

Comment: @RobertW.: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the real line with the Borel sigma algebra and Lebesgue measure. There exists a subset $A$ of the Cantor set $C$ which is not a Borel set. [It can be shown that the cardinality of the Borel sigma algebra is that of the real line  so not every subset of an uncountable set can be  a Borel set]]. Now take $f_n=0$ for all $n$ and $f=I_A$. Then $f_n \to f$ a.e. (since $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ whenever $x \notin C$)  and $f$ is not Borel measurable.